# Rails Bootstrap Modal not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have included Bootstrap modal inside my page. But my page just gets grey out when i press on the button and no pop dialog appears. However, when i press the ESC button, the dialog flashes once before exiting. Another instance i tried was, i included `//= bootstrap/modal` inside my application.js file. Inside this file i also had the line `//= bootstrap`. When i have both of this line included, the modal only stays for less than 1 second when i press the button.

Below is the code of my view page,

```
<% provide(:title, "Log in") %>
<div class="center jumbotron">
<h1> Kaching </h1>
<div class = "row" >
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :logID, "Log ID" %>
    <%= f.text_field :logID %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit "Log In", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Small Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a small modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show the script tag of bootstrap.js. It is working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f6n0yovx/)

Comment: i am using bootstrap-sass. Can i ask if i am suppose to have bootstrap.js specifically in my app/assets/javascripts folders? How do i check that bootstrap is loading correctly in my application? Please guide me on this, been working for days. thanks

Comment: open browser console . select script tab. in that you will find a dropdown list that contains all loaded script files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be no issue regarding your code. For the sake of clarity,  i will be explaining all the step regarding modal implementation.

steps 
1. include bootstrap.js in your JavaScript, and kindly check there is only bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min; both of them should not present.

2.Modal calling step should be

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login
 </button>
```

3.On calling the modal, the codes are

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Please Login</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="user name">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary info">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do i check if bootstrap is working? i am using bootstrap-sass in my gem. Please guide me on this. Have been trying for days to solve this problem.

Comment: you have to download the file from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download ,then click on download bootstrap, then extract the file, either copy the file bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js from folder named js and paste it your app./assets/javascripts.. do tell me its working or not!!!

Comment: yeah,my problem is solved after adding in the bootstrap.js. However, now it clashes with my other javascript in the application. Any idea why this happen or what can i do to prevent this? The javascript i use in my another view is inside a <script> tag. Thanks in advance

Comment: from my opinion you have to make that script  into a javascript file, and call from there..also would you accept the answer??

Comment: Hi, i have make my script into another javascript file but is not working that smoothly compared to the original placing. Sorry, but i do not know how to accept your answer?

Comment: I know this is old, but it was because I had both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min in my js folder.